# What is the intersection of this infinite amount of open sets?

Tags: general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces

Say I have the following

$$\bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \left(-\frac{1}{n}, \frac{1}{n}\right)$$

What is the value of this intersection of an infinite amount of open sets?

Comment: This intersection contains all real numbers $x$ such that $-1/n < x < 1/n$. Can you name such a number? Another one?

Comment: I see you know the answer now. But you might be interested in this: try to find an infinite union of closed sets that is not closed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

HINT: There is exactly one real number in that intersection: what is it? Once you’ve identified it, you should go on to prove that if $x$ is any other real number, then there is some $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ such that $x\notin\left(-\frac1n,\frac1n\right)$.

Comment: Cheers..I see it now..if I pick any number other than zero I can find an $n$ such that $x$ is not in that interval.

Comment: @dukenukem: Yep, that’s exactly right.